# Make all elements in an array lowercase and remove whitespace - using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of postcodes that I have created by reading a text file. I would lik eto step through each item in the array and make it lowercase, and remove any whitespace. So far I have the following:

```js
var postCodesCovered = new Array();
$.get('postcodes.txt', function(data){
  postCodesCovered = data.split('\n');
});
$.each(postCodesCovered , function(){
  $(this).toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick though. Is it because I am not setting the values back to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.get()` is `async` you need to move your code in the `success` callback, and you don't need to use `this`.

```
var postCodesCovered;
$.get('postcodes.txt', function(data) {
    postCodesCovered = data.split('\n');
    $.each(postCodesCovered, function(index, value) {
        postCodesCovered[index] = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });

    // Do something with the data here
});
```

Comment: I've tried running this, but the values don't seem to have changed at all - they match exactly what's in the text file still...

Answer (score 2):

@satpal is right - you need to process your list in the success callback. Each will iterate over the array items but you want to transform them into lowercase so map would be a better choice. Map takes an array and transforms each item returning a new array. See the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) docs for more info.

```
var postCodesCovered = [];
$.get('postcodes.txt', function(data) {
    postCodesCovered = $.map(data.split('\n'), function(value, index) {
        return value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated: arguments to map callback are value, then index - the reverse of each. Thanks for reminding me @void

Answer (score 0):

ry this...

```js
var postCodesCovered = new Array();
$.each(postCodesCovered , function(idx, val){
  postCodesCovered[idx] = $(this).toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertArray(CapsArray){
    lowcaseArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <CapsArray.length; i++) {
            lowcaseArray.push(CapsArray[i].replace(/\s+/g,"").toLowerCase());
        }
 return lowcaseArray;
}
```

The function above should do the job.

```
var YourLowCaseArray = convertArray(YourCapsArrayHere);
```